# Why can't gotos in Lua jump out of functions?

Tags: lua

From the Programming In Lua book 3rd edition page 38

> **Exercise 4.5:** Can you explain why Lua has the restriction that a `goto` cannot jump out of a function? (Hint: how would you implement that feature?)

I have a few guesses as to why it may be so:

- If you jump from one function into another and the second one returns, where does the PC go?
- If you have `a = f()` but f does a `goto` to after that line of code, what is the value of `a`?
- Is it not possible to define a standard behaviour because of different platforms' calling conventions?

I wonder how the author would answer that question. Maybe I'll e-mail him.

In the meantime, does anybody else have some ideas?

Comment: I think it's [because of the velociraptors](http://xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: Platform issues shouldn't matter. Not only is lua implemented in portable ANSI C but Lua functions do not use the C stack for their stack frames (this is needed to be able to implement coroutines portably). Other than that, you are on the right track - don't worry about searching for a canonical answer because there are many reasons to limit gotos like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your guesses are hinting at the answer.  The reason is because the `goto` statement and its destination must reside in the same stack frame.  The program context before and after the `goto` need to be the same otherwise the code being jumped to won't be running in its correct stack frame and its behavior will be undefined.  `goto` in C has the same restrictions for the same reasons.

The C standard library also provides `longjmp()` and `setjump()` which do allow you to implement a form of "goto" out of the current stack frame.  `setjmp()` saves the current stack context.  You can then call `longjmp()` to unwind the stack back to where you called `setjmp()`.  You cannot call `longjmp()` after the function which called `setjump()` exits.

Comment: Lua says: 1. Can't jump to within a block. 2. Can't jump out of functions. 3. Can't jump into the scope of local variables.
Rule #1 already disallows jumping into functions, so if rule #2 didn't exist, then we could only jump out into the global scope. Does jumping into the global scope still create problems? Does the global scope even have a proper stack frame?

Comment: The global scope is actually an anonymous function, whose body is the entire `chunk` passed to `lua_load()`. The global scope can still have local variables, and all the same corner cases apply. There was extensive discussion of `goto` on the [Lua-L](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.lua.general) list in 2010 and 2011 when Lua 5.2 work releases were first exploring the issues surrounding `goto` and related keywords such as `continue`. Search the archives for words like "goto", "scope", "block", "local".